# Creating a TCP server in the Linux kernel with error: passing argument 2 of ‘server_socket->ops->accept’

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel

sdfsdfsdf

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/net.h>
#include <linux/inet.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Your Name");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("TCP Server Socket Kernel Module");

#define SERVER_PORT 8080

static struct socket *server_socket = NULL;

static int tcp_server_init(void) {
    int error;

    // Step 1: Create the TCP socket
    struct socket *sock;
    error = sock_create_kern(&init_net, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, &sock);
    if (error < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to create server socket: %d\n", error);
        return error;
    }
    server_socket = sock;

    // Step 2: Bind the socket
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    error = server_socket->ops->bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                                     sizeof(server_addr));
    if (error < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to bind server socket: %d\n", error);
        sock_release(server_socket);
        return error;
    }

    // Step 3: Set the socket to listen
    error = server_socket->ops->listen(server_socket, 5);
    if (error < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to listen on server socket: %d\n", error);
        sock_release(server_socket);
        return error;
    }

    // Step 4: Accept incoming connections
    while (1) {
        struct socket *client_socket = NULL;
        struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
        int client_len = sizeof(client_addr);

        // Accept the client connection
        error = server_socket->ops->accept(server_socket, &client_socket, 0, false);
        if (error < 0) {
            printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to accept client connection: %d\n", error);
            sock_release(server_socket);
            return error;
        }

        // Step 5: Handle client connections
        // Implement your logic to communicate with the client here
        // You can use the client_socket to send and receive data

        // Clean up the client socket
        if (client_socket != NULL)
            sock_release(client_socket);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void tcp_server_exit(void) {
    if (server_socket != NULL)
        sock_release(server_socket);
}

module_init(tcp_server_init);
module_exit(tcp_server_exit);
```

why this code have error message with error: passing argument 2 of ‘server_socket->ops->accept’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
58 |         error = server_socket->ops->accept(server_socket, &client_socket, 0, false);
|                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                                                           |
|                                                           struct socket **

i want to make tcp server in kernel-level

Comment: If you haven't created the client socket then you need to call something like kernel_accept https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/net/socket.c#L3469